# Can JMeter record capture requests from a .razor page?

Tags: jmeter

Currently on launching the login page of the application (which is a .razor page) through JMeter after providing all the necessary JMeter configurations, the contents of the page are not displayed in UI.

If the source of the request is .razor and JMeter by itself is not capable of recording it, how can such applications be recorded through JMeter? Is there any work around?

Answer (score 0):

As per Wikipedia [ASP.NET Razor article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Razor)

> Razor is an ASP.NET programming syntax used to create dynamic web pages with the C# or VB.NET programming languages.

JMeter doesn't know anything about the backend languages/technologies/patterns/whatever, it just sends [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods), waits for responses and measures time in-between

In case of HTTP and HTTPS protocols you can record the requests using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

Looking at Introduction to [Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) it doesn't do any magic so JMeter should capture the requests and be capable of replaying them.

Just pay attention to these "async" calls, real browsers execute [AJAX requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) in parallel so if this is your case - you might want to put HTTP Request samplers representing async calls under the [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/)

If JMeter is not recording anything the reasons could be in:

- JMeter configuration is not correct: check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) and your browser console window
- The protocol(s) in use are not only HTTP/HTTPS, if there is something like [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) under the hood - you won't be able to record it with JMeter, you will have to inspect the requests using your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and look for a way of replicating them using suitable [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)